# Как заменить словосочетание в строке на 1 символ

Tags: python, python-3.7

В строке 'в чем смысл вопросительный знак' нужно заменить словосочетание 'вопросительный знак' на соответствующий символ. Для этого я написал этот код:

```
cmd = "в чем смысл вопросительный знак"

if ("вопросительный знак" in cmd):
for x in "вопросительный знак":
    cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

print(cmd + '?')
```

В общем нужно чтобы программа удаляла только 'вопросительный знак' не трогая остальное и вместо этого добавлялся '?'. Но для выполнения этой цели моих знаний явно не хватает, так что искренне прошу помочь. И еще, пожалуйста, не кидайтесь в меня помидорами из-за непонятного кода, сначала он хоть как-то работал, но потом я напортачил и немного его поломал.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: cmd = cmd.replace("вопросительный знак", "?")

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Позвольте внесу свои 5 копеек. Надеюсь, что еще актуально.

1) То что цикл `for` у Вас без отступа, это наверно случайно вышло, а если нет, то не забудьте, что отступ нужен, иначе инструкция `if` выполнятся не будет и вызовется ошибка.
2) В скрипте Вы "говорите" чтобы цикл для переменной `x` принимал как значение, каждый символ из строки `"вопросительный знак"` и в теле цикла для `cmd`, которая имеет значение `"в чем смысл вопросительный знак"` применяете метод `replace`.
Тем самым при первой итерации `x = "в"` из `cmd` "удалятся" (а вернее заменятся на `""`) все символы `"в"` и так далее с каждым символом.
3) метод `strip()` сам по себе ничего удалять не будет, нужно что-то указывать, а точнее символ из начала или конца строки, например:

```
str = "***привет удачи в питоне!**"
str = str.strip('*')
print(str)
```

Результат:

```
>>>'привет удачи в питоне!'
```

А так Вам уже ответили, как лучше всего (или можно) делать замену.
Еще можно загнать замену на вопросительный знак в функцию, если вдруг нужно будет часто такое делать и плодить лишние строки кода. Например так:

```py
    cmd = "в чем смысл вопросительный знак"

    def replace_quest_mark(str):
        repl = "вопросительный знак"
        if repl in str:
            str = str.replace(repl, "?") #как вариант еще можно с убиранием пробела в конце 
            #str = str.replace(repl, "").strip(" ") + "?"
        return str

    cmd = replace_quest_mark(cmd)
    print(cmd)
```

Придумывать можно много. Удачи!